# jqGrid: Help displaying current search to user.

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid and I need to be able to display the current search that's being performed on the grid. We use the navGrid to give the users options to filter through what's been pulled back and I'd like to be able to show the users the current filters being applied to the data. I have a label on the page and some javascript that grabs the current queries and displays it onSearch:

```
function SetCurrentFilters () {
    var currentFilters = $('#DataManagementGrid').getGridParam("postData").filters;

    document.getElementById("lblCurrentFilters").innerHTML = currentFilters;
}
```

It displays json:

{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"IsActive","op":"eq","data":"true"},{"field":"LastModifiedBy","op":"cn","data":"cheese"}]}

My question is, is there a better route? Or should I just work with the json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse this JSON and read the field name/value and show it in HTML.
Just an idea, not a solution though :

```
function SetCurrentFilters () {
    var currentFilters = $('#DataManagementGrid').getGridParam("postData").filters;

      var htmlString='';
      var data = $.parseJSON(currentFilters);

    $.each(data.rules, function(idx, obj) {
       htmlString += obj.field + ' ' + obj.op + ' ' + obj.data + '<br />;
    });

    document.getElementById("lblCurrentFilters").innerHTML = currentFilters;
}
```

Apply some logic in the loop to check what kind of operator is there and what you want to show i.e. eq for ' = ' etc.